# XMPP - vCard Avatar Update Notification to Offline Rosters

Tags: xmpp, smack, xmppframework, vcf-vcard

When User A and User B, both are online and one of them changes the avatar, all the rosters of the User receive a presence stanza with vcard-temp update element with the sha1 hash of the image used as avatar.

```
<presence from='juliet@capulet.com/balcony'>
  <x xmlns='vcard-temp:x:update'>
    <photo>sha1-hash-of-image</photo>
  </x>
</presence>
```

However, no such notification/stanza is generated for the users which are offline at that time, So such a client shows no change in the avatar displayed.

How can an offline user can get v-card updates from rosters, when there is any change? I don't wish to ask for vCard for all the rosters, even if there is no change.

Answer (score 0):

I think a client that support the protocol should include the avatar in all presence packet, not just on change. As explained in [XEP-0153: vCard-Based Avatars](http://www.xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0153.html):

> If a client supports the protocol defined herein, it MUST include the
>   update child element in every presence broadcast it sends and SHOULD
>   also include the update child in directed presence stanzas (e.g.,
>   directed presence sent when joining Multi-User Chat (XEP-0045) [5]
>   rooms).

It means offline users will get the correct presence and can update the avatar when they are both online.

Comment: Hi @mickaël-rémond Yes that is the Issue, **Both must be online at the same time**, only then the Avatar changes can be notified even if the update child is included in all the presence stanzas. I wish to display the avatar changes even if the other user goes offline after changing the avatar.

Comment: Then you need to rely on other mechanisms like: query avatar for update or use PEP / Pubsub based mechanisms.

Comment: Are there any improvement on this @sainiankit? How have you handled offline cases since then?